# python handling large json response from wikipedia api

Tags: python, json, api, mediawiki

I am accessing the wikipedia api to grab the text from a page. I'm using the parse api call with the page name. [Click here for example, then hit the make request button to get the response.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Kobe%20Bryant&contentmodel=wikitext) It gives you the html of the whole site as an element in the json object and allows you to parse the items you need by providing a byte offset for each section in the wiki page. Is there a better way to handle this then to load the whole response into memory? Right now, all I can think of is to use json.loads() to create a dict and then split the string by each of the byte offset it specifies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson), an iterative JSON parser. This package allows you to iterate over nodes, for example:

```
import ijson

f = urlopen('http://.../')
objects = ijson.items(f, 'earth.europe.item')
cities = (o for o in objects if o['type'] == 'city')
for city in cities:
   do_something_with(city)
```